# how can we us this with Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

this formula need to be copy-pasted down everytime need to use array formula any idea how can be done

```js
=if(and(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("agreed",F2))=true,F2<>"Disagreed"),1,0)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is not supported by `ArrayFormula`, that you need to use `*` or nested `IF` instead.

Besides, `ISNUMBER` returns a boolean such that `=true` is not needed.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("agreed",F2:F))*(F2:F<>"Disagreed"),1,0))
```